# WSO2 IOT Server disconnected from broker

Tags: raspberry-pi, wso2, mqtt, iot, broker

Why cannot I run two testAgents(of raspberry pi) at the same time?

When I run them in two separate raspberry pi boards with different deviceIds, when one is connected to the broker other one gets disconnected. Then the next one is connected and 1st gets disconnected... They don't do anything else.

I cannot guess any reason for this and I tried my best to solve this. I tried with same user, different users, same access token, different access tokens. But same thing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They will be using the same MQTT client ID. The broker will always disconnect the first client that connects with a client ID when a second client connects with the same client ID.

The logs from the broker should show this happening.

Comment: I noticed that... How can I change it? I have created two devices in my devicemgt console. But broker takes the same client Id...